# HTML anchors not working in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, anchor

I have menu with this link:

```
 <a title="Haluamme palvella" href="http://mydevsite.fi/#haluamme-palvella" rel="page-22"><span>Haluamme palvella</span></a>
```

and I've placed this link in my page:

```
<a id="haluamme-palvella" name="#haluamme-palvella" class="anchor">.</a>
```

and this is the css:

```
a.anchor {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -155px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Problem is that this doesn't work in IE.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the # From the "Name"

```
<a id="haluamme-palvella" name="haluamme-palvella" class="anchor">.</a>
```